# If a cell in column A doesn't match a cell anywhere in sheet 2, column A, delete the row that contains Sheet 1 Column A

Tags: excel

Sorry if the title is confusing. I have a bunch of unique Loan Numbers in Column A in sheet 1 and 2. I want a formula that will delete the row in sheet 1 if the cell in Column A doesn't exist anywhere in sheet 2, Column A.

Comment: formula can't delete rows. You need VBA for this

Comment: @simoco I can manually delete them if they were colored. What would the formula be to highlight a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in `B1` of sheet1:

```
=AND(A1<>"",ISNA(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)))
```

and drag it down.

Formula above returns `TRUE` if value doesn't exist in column `A` of sheet2.

Next step - you can filter column `B` of sheet1 for values `TRUE` and delete visible rows.

---

Additionally, you can use [Conditional Formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx) for highlighting thouse cells.

Select entire column `A` on sheet1 and add CF rule with formula `=B1`

[image]

**Reslut:**

[image]